# nodejs returning empty array even after using async, await

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to generate a list of similar movies for a movie-recommendation website, but the final array thats being returned is empty. Please refer the code and console output below.

```
const getRecommendations = async (email) => {
    const randomSeedIds = await getRandomSeed(email);
    console.log(randomSeedIds);
    try {
        const movies = []; //the array im returning
        randomSeedIds.forEach(async id => {
            const simMovies = await movieApi.getSimilar(id, 5);// generates list of similar movies
            console.log(simMovies);
            simMovies.forEach(movie => movies.push(movie));// pushing similar movies to movies arr
        });
        console.log(movies);
        return movies;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Console Output: As you can see the database is returning records perfectly.

```
[ '0109830', '1375666' ] // movies from which im generating recommendations

[] // array im trying to return (why is this empty ?) 

[ { title: 'Insomnia',
    imdbId: '0278504',
    poster: '/images/278504.jpg' },
  { title: 'Patlabor: The Movie (Kidô keisatsu patorebâ: The Movie)',
    imdbId: '0100339',
    poster: '/images/100339.jpg' },
  { title: 'Dark Knight Rises, The',
    imdbId: '1345836',
    poster: '/images/1345836.jpg' },
]// similar movies of seed movie1

[ { title: 'Train of Life (Train de vie)',
    imdbId: '0170705',
    poster: '/images/170705.jpg' },
  { title: 'Tiger and the Snow, The (La tigre e la neve)',
    imdbId: '0419198',
    poster: '/images/419198.jpg' },
  { title: 'Life is a Miracle (Zivot je cudo)',
    imdbId: '0322420',
    poster: '/images/322420.jpg' },
 ]// similar movies of seed2
```

Comment: Try declaring the movies array using var instead of const. The value of a const cannot be changed.

Comment: Are you using `await getRecommendations()` in your call ?

Do you get an error message ?

Comment: I changed the for each loop to a for of loop and now it works perfectly.